# Can't figure out how to read the data passed in from form data

Tags: ajax, node.js, coffeescript

having trouble accessing a file I'm sending over in a formData object into node.  Code in coffeescript.  Sending:

```
formData = new FormData()
        formData.append("upload", file)
        $.ajax
            url: "/onboard/groups/csv"
            method: "POST"
            dataType: "json"
            cache: false
            data: formData
            contentType: false
            processData: false
            success: (data) ->
                console.log "OStore post-processed data: ", data
                callback(null, data)
```

Receiving:

```
router.post "/onboard/groups/csv", (req, res, next) ->
file = req.files?['upload']?
fs.readFile file, (err,data) ->
    console.log err if err
    return file = data
console.log "postfile: ", file
```

Not very experienced with fs but should I be doing something differently to access the file?  use path?  thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to use something like https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy.

The file being uploaded is in the request, but is not yet on the filesystem it is in the memory of the server. So, we can not read it from the file system and need to read it from the request.

Something like busboy, or any other streaming parser library for Node will help you accomplish this!

Comment: There has to be a core module that I could use for this, no?

Comment: @Fedreg No, express does not include anything really in its core so that it can remain "lean" - So most everything is added in as needed ("middleware"). Parsing streaming data (files) is somewhat complex, or at least it can be.